# Can't get ip2long() to work

Tags: php, ip, ip2long

I'm trying to compare some IP addresses that are stored as strings. I read about `ip2long()` to convert the string to an integer so I'm playing around with it to see if it would do what I want. So, initially, I'm just trying to see what the converted IP looks like. I wrote the following code to look at that but nothing is being converted. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
<?php
foreach($form->data[vicondb] as $video_net_key) 
{
    if ($video_net_key['ipaddress'] != null)
    {
        echo "The IP address is " . $video_net_key['ipaddress'];
        $iplong = ip2long($video_net_key['ipaddress']);
        echo " --- The ip long conversion is " . $iplong . "<br>";
    }

} // End foreach($form->data[vicondb] as $video_net_key)

echo "End of both foreach statements<br>";
?>
```

Here is a sample of the result:

> The IP address is 172.26.0.10 --- The ip long conversion is
>
> The IP address is 172.26.0.31 --- The ip long conversion is
>
> The IP address is 172.26.0.32 --- The ip long conversion is
>
> The IP address is 172.26.0.33 --- The ip long conversion is

Here is a sample of the `var_dump()` for IP and converted to integer:

```
string(12) "172.26.0.10 "
bool(false)
string(12) "172.26.0.31 "
bool(false)
string(12) "172.26.0.32 "
bool(false)
```

Comment: `var_dump($video_net_key['ipaddress']); var_dump($iplong);`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your code. It shows the ip address for the first line and shows 0 for all the iplong variables. However, when I put in an IP address in an online converter I get 2887385121 for the IP 172.26.0.33 but it comes up 0 in my script.

Comment: And the var_dump on the IP shows length 11?

Comment: Here is a sample of the dump: string(12) "172.26.0.10 " bool(false)
string(12) "172.26.0.31 " bool(false)
string(12) "172.26.0.32 " bool(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trim the IP as it seems to have a trailing space and is not valid:

```
$iplong = ip2long(trim($video_net_key['ipaddress']));
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Comment: Make sure to use `var_dump()` when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something similar like this

"Because PHP's integer type is signed, and many IP addresses will result in negative integers on 32-bit architectures, you need to use the "%u" formatter of sprintf() or printf() to get the string representation of the unsigned IP address." *[From ip2long php.net article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php)*

This should work:

```
echo " --- The ip long conversion is " . sprintf("%u", ip2long($video_net_key['ipaddress'])) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code and get the following:    The IP address is 172.26.0.10 --- The ip long conversion is 0
    The IP address is 172.26.0.31 --- The ip long conversion is 0
    The IP address is 172.26.0.32 --- The ip long conversion is 0 When I put in an IP address in an online converter I get 2887385121 for the IP 172.26.0.33

Comment: @ChessDad I don't know any other explanation for this problem.